# Storing dynamic values from input fields in a JS object, and converting to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

1. How can I add two values from two HTML `<input>` fields to a JS object?
2. How can I then convert that object into JSON?

Code:

```
$("input").each(function() { var jsonObj=[];        
    var id = $(#box1).val();
    var email = $(#box2).val();
    item = {};
    item ["title"] = id;
    item ["email"] = email;
    jsonObj.push(item);  
});
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual* notation. If you're dealing with objects in memory, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: You need quotes around your selectors `$('#box1')`, also note your variable name is `jsonObj` but it is actually an array.

Comment: Ok then How to Push values into JSON dynamically in javascript,

Comment: you do not push anything into JSON, you create an object, like your `item` object or an array like your `jsonObj` variable, and then stringify it to get a JSON string `JSON.stringify(myobject)` or `JSON.stringify(myarray)`, if you are wanting to add elements to an array or add properties to an object, you are already doing so

Comment: think of JSON as a textual representation of javascript object in memory.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F5B4L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (with the selectors put in quotes) will successfully store an object with the properties `title` and `email` in the array...briefly. Then the array will be eligible for garbage collection because you don't keep a reference to it anywhere outside the function.

If your goal is to keep track of the information longer than one iteration of the `each` loop, declare and initialize your array *outside* of the function:

```
var arr=[];
$("input").each(function() {         
    var id = $("#box1").val();
    var email = $("#box2").val();
    item = {};
    item ["title"] = id;
    item ["email"] = email;
    arr.push(item);  
});
```

But I can't immediately see a reason you'd do that repeatedly while looping through the `input` elements on the page.

Comment: (T.J.Crowder)  How can I display the Stored Values in the Array of objects in an another function?

Comment: @zet: Provided the code looping over the inputs is called before you display it, and there are inputs on the page, `arr` will have something in it. I recommend you step back from your current task and work through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add submit button in HTML. and perform below operation when button clicks.

**HTML CODE**

```
<button id="submitButton">Save Values</button>
```

change **JS**

```
$("#submitButton").on('click',function() { 
    var jsonObj=  jsonObj || [];        
    var id = $("#box1").val();
    var email = $("#box2").val();
    item = {};
    item ["title"] = id;
    item ["email"] = email;
    jsonObj.push(item);  
});
```

Comment: Is jsonObj acts like an array or JSON array of objects  in this code,,

Comment: I have lot of confusions in JSON object,,

Comment: It acts like a array of json objects.

Comment: `var jsonObj=  jsonObj || [];` is utterly pointless. It's not like `jsonObj` will have a value at that point.